# Что делают идентификаторы препроцессора в объявлении функции С++?

Tags: c++, c

В исходных кодах движка Irrlicht я встретил непонятное для меня определение фунуции. В нем используются два идентификатора препроцессора:

```
#define IRRLICHT_API
#define IRRCALLCONV
```

А после они используются в определении функции:

```
extern "C" IRRLICHT_API IrrlichtDevice* IRRCALLCONV createDevice(
     video::E_DRIVER_TYPE deviceType = video::EDT_SOFTWARE,
     const core::dimension2d<u32>& windowSize = (core::dimension2d<u32>(640,480)),
     u32 bits = 16,
     bool fullscreen = false,
     bool stencilbuffer = false,
     bool vsync = false,
     IEventReceiver* receiver = 0);
```

Что делают эти идентификаторы?

Answer (score 7):

Они делают именно то, что следует из их положения в объявлении функции: дают автору кода возможность использовать препроцессор для того, чтобы "вставить" в объявление функции какие-то дополнительные квалификаторы.

Например, завтра он может решить сделать

```
#define IRRLICHT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#define IRRCALLCONV __cdecl
```

Вполне может быть это уже делается в рассматриваемом вами коде, в зависимости от конфигурации - вы просто не заметили.

В приведенном же вами случае это просто пустые макро. В таком виде они ничего не делают.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по названию, `IRRLICHT_API` должен декларировать импорт или экспорт функции (например `__declspec(dllimport)`), а `IRRCALLCONV` соглашение о вызовах, используемое для данной функции (например `__stdcall`). Но если они объявлены как в вопросе, то они ничего не делают.